# Libgdx : Sprite want stop moving;

Tags: java, libgdx

I am trying to make a sprite walk to the mouse position. However, when the mouse is clicked and the sprite walks to the mouse position, it won't stop and keeps moving in the same direction.

Here's my code:

```js
public void render(float delta) {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1,1,1,1);
 Gdx.gl.glClear(GL30.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT); 
  
 if(Gdx.input.isTouched()){
     projected= new Vector3(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY(), 0);
     cam.unproject(projected);
   
     if(position.x != projected.x || position.y != projected.y){
 
                pathX = projected.x - position.x;
  pathY = projected.y - position.y;
   
  distance = (float) Math.sqrt(pathX * pathX + pathY * pathY);
  directionX = pathX / distance;
  directionY = pathY / distance;
            }
 }
  
 position.x += directionX * Speed * delta;
 position.y += directionY * Speed * delta;
}
```

Please help and thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is basically a duplicate of [How to stop drawing a SpriteBatch animation in libgdx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23088315/how-to-stop-drawing-a-spritebatch-animation-in-libgdx) || [how do I pause the SpriteAnimation in libGDX with a button to be able to view the current frame when pause button is pressed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12584171/how-do-i-pause-the-spriteanimation-in-libgdx-with-a-button-to-be-able-to-view-th) , check out this article to see if it helps.

In short, you want to keep track of the player moving and when they get to the x, y coordinates of your mouse, set the moving to false. Have the logic within your render to only render when your boolean is true.

Comment: I can't see all of your code but I'm assuming that you have a listener for when the mouse is clicked. At that point, I would grab the x, y and set those to class variables so you have access to it outside of your render method but you can reuse them where you are creating your Vector3